# How can I run 360 servomotor MG996R on micropython usign esp32 dev kit board?

Tags: esp32, micropython

I need your help, I can't run 360 servomotor on esp32 with micropython.
I checked all internet to find solution to this problem but I couldn't find it.
Strange is that same motor type MG996R with 180 degrees works perfectly, 360 version of motor doesn't want to run on esp32. I tried 360 servomotor on arduino and is working fine. Please help me find solution
Specs of servomotors:
https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995-robot-servo-180-rotation/
https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995-robot-servo-360-180-rotation/

The code I'm usign is verry simple example of running servos in micropython & esp32

```
from machine import Pin, Timer, PWM
from time import sleep
motor = Pin(23)
servo = PWM(motor)
servo.freq(50)
servo.duty(tried all values here)
```

Comment: Can you show the Arduino code that works for the two motors?

Comment: HI. Sure, this is the code for arduino
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;
Serial.begin(9600);
servo.attach(9);
servo.write(70);
delay(1000);  
servo.write(90);

Comment: If the same code on Arduino works for both motors, but only one of the motors works on the ESP32, that sounds like an electronics problem not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made this mistake twice in my projects. Make sure your grounds(DC-) are joined if you are using a separate power supply for the servo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).